# How to authenticate oauth, Magento 2.0 SOAP in Ruby

Tags: ruby, magento2, savon

Having a problem authenticating to Magento 2 SOAP with oauth credentials.

For a magento 1.9 version this is very straightforward:

```
client = Savon.client(
  wsdl: "https://example.com/api/soap/?wsdl=1",
  log: true,
  pretty_print_xml: true
)
session_id = client.call(:login, message: { username: "username", apiKey: "key" })body[:login_response][:login_return]
client.call(:call, message:{resource_path: 'catalog_product.list', session_id: session_id}).body
```

Works as expected. With oauth it gets bit more complicated. 
I tried all kind of different things, like:

```
client = Savon.client(
    wsdl: "http://example.com/index.php/soap/default?wsdl_list=1",
    soap_header: { 'Authorization:' => "Basic xxxx"},
    pretty_print_xml: true
)

client.call(:call, message:{resource_path: 'catalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1'}).body
```

Hope somebody already made an oauth-magento 2 soap integration and give me some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new integration from admin to get authentication keys. These links will be useful resource:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html
https://gist.github.com/rafaelstz/ecab668b80fece4d9acdb9c5358b3173

Comment: Yes, that is clear to me. Actually for people looking for that flow (and don't want to use devise): https://gist.github.com/heldopslippers/45bebe07a6f5fdfbb91f0c96c3b4de68 This is a working example. My question is, how do you use it with Savon (soap gem and Magento 2.0).